# $\sum_{i\in X}x_i$ is convergent implies that $\sum_{i\in X}|x_i|$ is covergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a set, and for each $i\in X$, let $x_i$ be a real number. We say that $\sum_{i\in X}x_i$ converges iff there is a real number $a$ such that for every $\varepsilon\gt 0$, there is a finite subset $\Omega$ of $X$ such that for all finite sets $\Omega'$ with $\Omega\subseteq\Omega'\subseteq X$, we have

$|a-\sum_{i\in\Omega'}x_i|\lt\varepsilon$.

What I'm struggling with is, when $\sum_{i\in X}x_i$ is convergent , how to show that $\sum_{i\in X}|x_i|$ is also covergent?

Comment: @JoseAvilez In my textbook, it says that convergence of an unordered summation in $\mathbb{R}$  is the same as absolute convergence, i.e., if $\{a_k\}_{k\in X}$ is a family in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\sum_{k\in X}a_k$ converges iff $\sum_{k\in X}{|a_k|}\lt\infty$.

Comment: @JoseAvilez pretty sure this is indeed true.

Comment: i think the otherway is true and is used to check covergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assumption there exists a finite subset  $\Omega_0$ such that for any  finite $\Omega\supset  \Omega_0$ we have $$\left |\sum_{i\in  \Omega}x_i-a\right |<1$$ Thus for any finite $\Omega\supset  \Omega_0$ we get  $$\left |\sum_{i\in  \Omega}x_i-\sum_{i\in  \Omega_0}x_i\right |<2$$ Let $X_+$ denote the set of all indices such that $x_i\ge 0.$ For any finite set $\Omega\subset X_+$ we have $$\sum_{i\in \Omega}x_i \le \sum_{i\in \Omega\setminus \Omega_0}x_i+ \sum_{i\in \Omega_0\cap X_+}x_i\\ = \left |\sum_{i\in \Omega\cup \Omega_0}x_i- \sum_{i\in  \Omega_0}x_i\right |+\sum_{i\in \Omega_0\cap X_+}x_i\\ \le 2+ \sum_{i\in \Omega_0\cap X_+}x_i $$ Therefore $$\sup_{\Omega\subset X_+}\sum_{i\in \Omega}x_i<\infty$$ Similarly (by considering the series with terms $-x_i$)$$\sup_{\Omega\subset X_-}\sum_{i\in \Omega}(-x_i)<\infty$$ where $X_-=X\setminus X_+.$ This implies the conclusion as $$\sum_{i\in \Omega}|x_i| =
\sum_{i\in \Omega\cap X_+}x_i+ \sum_{i\in \Omega\cap X_-}(-x_i)$$

Comment: When you write "For any finite subset $\Omega\subset X_+$", I think the first equality after that should be $\leq$, since you don't necessarily have $\Omega_0\cap \Omega=\Omega_0\cap X_+$.  $\Omega_0\cap\Omega$ may be smaller, unless we are additionally assuming $\Omega_0\cap X_+\subseteq \Omega$ (which I don't think is what we want).

Comment: @MW Thanks a lot   for spotting the misprint.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sum_{i\in X}x_i$ convergent in this sense, let $n > 0$ be given. Then there is finite $\Omega = \Omega_n$ such that for any finite $\Omega' \supseteq \Omega$, we have that
$$
\left| a - \sum_{i\in \Omega'}x_i\right| < \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}
$$
But that implies that for any finite set $\Phi \subseteq X \setminus \Omega$, we have that
$$
\left|\sum_{i\in \Phi}x_i\right| < \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
$$
So, if $\Phi$ is any finite subset of $X \setminus \Omega$ and $\Phi^+$ and $\Phi^-$, are the subsets of $\Phi$ such that $x_i \ge 0$ whenever $i \in \Phi^+$ and $x_i < 0$ whenever $i \in \Phi^-$, we have that
$$
\sum_{i\in \Phi}|x_i| = \left|\sum_{i\in \Phi^+}\right| + \left|\sum_{i\in \Phi^+}x_i\right|  <  \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
Repeating this for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ gives us a sequence of finite subsets $\Omega_n$ of $X$, such that $s_n = \sum_{i \in \Omega_n}|x_i|$ is a Cauchy sequence tending to a limit $a'$ such that $\sum_{i \in X}|x_i|$ converges to $a'$ in the given sense. (I used $2^n$ rather than $n$ to make sure that $|s_n - s_{n-1}| < \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ so that the $s_n$ converge to a finite limit.)

Comment: Deleted my last comment since I think you don't actually need $\Omega_n$ to be nested for your argument.  However, if you DO make them nested you could dispense with the $2^n$ business. (You can easily take them to be nested since if $\Omega$ satisfies the definition of conditional convergence then so does any superset.)

Comment: @MW: thanks. I'll leave my answer as it is because the $2^n$ business is a useful trick, albeit one that can be bypassed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall \epsilon > 0$, since $\sum_{i\in X} x_i$ is convergent, there exists a finite subset $\Omega \subset X$ such that $|a - \sum_{i\in \Omega'} x_i| < \epsilon$ for any finite subset $\Omega \subset \Omega' \subset X$.

Note $b = \sum_{i\in \Omega} |x_i|$, then

Consider

$$
\begin{align}
f: \omega &\mapsto \sum_{i\in \omega} x_i \\
g: \omega &\mapsto \sum_{i\in \omega} |x_i| \\
\{\Omega' \setminus \Omega &| \Omega \subset \Omega' \subset X\} \to \mathbb{R} \\
\end{align}
$$

And since ${x_i}$ is given, $X \setminus \Omega$ can be divided into two subsets $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that $x_i \ge 0$ for $i \in X_1$ and $x_i < 0$ for $i \in X_2$.

Then define

$$
\begin{align}
f_+: \omega &\mapsto \sum_{i\in \omega \cap X_1} x_i \\
f_-: \omega &\mapsto \sum_{i\in \omega \cap X_2} |x_i| \\
\end{align}
$$

Then $f = f_+ - f_-$ and $g = f_+ + f_-$.

Then one can prove $\sup(2f) \ge \sup(g)$. And then verify

$$
\begin{align}
|b - \sup(g)| < 2\epsilon
\end{align}
$$

Edit: remove all things with $b$, but pay attention to $\sup{g}$. If it is controlled by $2\epsilon$, it is enough to prove its convergence.

Comment: You chose $b$ depending on $\Omega$.  If you do that, $\sum_{i\in X}|x_i|$ will ***not*** converge to $b$.

Answer (score 0):

For every finite subset $I$ of $X$ take $s_I=\sum_{j \in I}x_j$; then the definition in the OP can be restated as $\lim_I s_I=a$ where the limit is taken in the net sense (with the partial order being inclusion which clearly satisfies the required majorant condition for the net partial order which ensures unicity of the limit since if $I,I_1$ are finite sets, $I \cup I_1$ is a finite set majorizing both).

Now if $s_I$ is increasing (in the sense that $I \subset J$ or abstractly $I \le J$ in the partial order defining the net) then $s_I \le s_J$, the net limit exists always (if possibly infinite) and is $\sup s_I$ finite or infinite. This is almost self-evident from the definition of the supremum and the net limit.

In particular, it follows that if $\sum_j |a_j|$ as above is not convergent, for every $M$ there is $J_M$ finite with $\sum_{j \in J_M}|a_j| >M$, but then considering $J_M^+, J_M^-$ the subsets of $J_M$ where $a_j \ge 0$ and $a_j<0$ respectively at least one of $|\sum_{j \in J_M^{\pm}}a_j| >M/2$, and call $K_M$ the corresponding $J_M^{\pm}$

But now assuming $\sum_j a_j=a$, pick $J$ finite st $|\sum_{j \in Q} a_j-a| <1$ for all finite $Q \supset J$ and let $b=\sum_{j \in J}|a_j|$. Then picking $M >2(b+|a|+1)$ and  considering $J_1=J \cup K_M$ so $|\sum_{j \in J_1}a_j-a|<1$ and using the triangle inequality we have the contradiction:

$$b+|a|+1<M/2< |\sum_{j \in K_M} a_j| \le |a|+1+b$$

Hence $\sup_J(\sum_{j \in J}|a_j|) <\infty$ where the supremum is taken on all finite susbsets of $X$ which means $\sum_{j\in X}|a_j|=\sup_J(\sum_{j \in J}|a_j|) < \infty $ converges as required.

The converse is of course true as in the usual sequence/series case (where if $X^{\pm}$ are the subsets where $a_j \ge 0$ and $a_j <0$ respectively, absolute convergence implies $\sum_{j \in X^+}a_j=b < \infty, \sum_{j \in X^-}(-a_j)=b_1 < \infty$ and taking $a=b-b_1$ one can then show that $\sum_{j \in X}a_j=a$)